# Htaccess https 301 problem

Tags: permalinks, redirect, htaccess, https

Since 2 weeks I have installed an SSL certificate on my domain. I have changed my base urls to https so my canonical url is https now. But now I need to force to https. I did this with the below htaccess change, but if I update my permalinks in admin now, Wordpress overwrites it to the old htaccess and my https redirect is gone.

Has anyone any experience with this?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/dev/$1 [R,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify either before # BEGIN WordPress or after # END WordPress. This part is modified by WP, once you change your permanlink